# Could not find: com.google.android.gms:play-services-*:9.8.00

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am using **com.google.android.gms:play-services-*:9.8.00** for GCM and ads service in gradle. Previously it works fine, but currently its not working.

It's showing below error now when build the apk:
`Could not find: com.google.android.gms:play-services-*:9.8.00`

Comment: I think the package name is wrong. Check my answer for more detail

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) will be helpful for you.In your case case 
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'`

Comment: @0xalihn did you find any solution. I am facing this issue too.

Comment: @jakeoliver Niko's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the services name, in your case it should be this two line in your build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'
```

And if you want to include all play-services (not recommended!)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Google Repository and its related repostories has been updated to the latest version. Check by going to the SDK Manager -> Extras Section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They switched from '... .00' to '... .0' - just remove the last '0'